# Favourite button tooltip is incorrect

Tags: bug, bookmarks, tooltips

Hovering over the favourite button on a question gives you a tooltip with the text:

> This is a favorite question (click again to undo)

Even if you haven't favourited the question.

Shouldn't it be something like `Click to favorite this question`?

Comment: What if it is already clicked?

Comment: You get the same message @JonW

Comment: But in that case if you click it you will un-favourite it. The message needs to be  suitable for both the selected *and* unselected states.

Comment: I was thinking of a different message depending on what state it is...

Comment: It's consistent with the voting arrows, except they don't show the "click again to Undo" until they are clicked.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Sorry - didn't see that question. It's not consistent with the answer accept button though! Please see my comment on Doorknob's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is that not correct?

The tooltip is telling you in what situation to click the star ("This is a favorite question").

It is also telling you that this can be undone ("(click again to undo)").

Comment: Hmmm... makes sense, but then why not make it consistent with the 'accept answer' button? Answer button is `Click to accept this answer because it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution (click again to undo)` so why not prepend `Click to` on the favourite button?