# Change the pop-up text for "favorite question" tooltip

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks, tooltips

Please do not duplicate this for one of the *similar* [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) report or [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) questions, which only ask "why" it is like this or state "it should not be" like this.
I am proposing an actual idea to change it ([feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)).

(TL;DR; further below for those who know the *issue*)

---

The current message when hovering the tooltip:

> This is a favorite question (click again to undo)

### The message is one of the states regardless

Currently, whether the question is a favorite or not, it states exactly the same message (as above).
This *could* be fine if the message was different, but the current message is one of the actual states of the tooltip.

So if it *is* a favorite then the message is fine as it states "this is a favorite", but if it's *not* a favorite then the message is telling me it is the opposite potential state to what it actually is.

This really is confusing, and while it's not exactly an admin control area button, I just think it's illogical enough to warrant a change.

### Someone's telling porkies

It is not a favorite question, I do not have any favorite questions *at all*.
This is even confirmed to me [in my profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/230506/james?tab=favorites):

> You have no favorite questions

The is confusing, because my profile states that I have no favorites but when on a question I'm told by a tooltip pop-up message that I do have a favorite.

In fact, if I were to *believe* the tooltip message, *every single* question on every Stack site would be a favorite...

> "I'm not upset that you lied to me, I'm upset that from now on I can't
>   believe you."
>    - [Friedrich Nietzsche](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrich_Nietzsche)

### Undo that which has not been done

I cannot "(click again to undo)" because I never did it in the first place.

> [undo](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/undo)
>
> To reverse the doing of; cause to be as if never done:

I cannot *reverse the doing of* something I have not done.
I cannot *cause to be as if never done* because it has already not has been never done (I didn't do it yet).

---

### TL;DR;

### A Simple Change

So, I am proposing to simply change the *static* text to something more logical, such as .

> Click to toggle favorite on or off

It's still not perfect given the amazingly worded functionality the site otherwise offers, but at least it's generic and not one of the possible states.

Also the visual state confirms it a bit, as when a question "is favorite" the star is gold, and when "not favorite" it's grey and *offy* looking (I know this is in play with the current message, but it still has an *incorrect* message).

(Although.. the HTML anchor's CSS class does currently change based on state -"not favorite" is `class="star-off"`, and "is favorite" is `class="star-off star-on"`, so something in the scripts already knows the state change, how hard would it be to... no, no, simple request James..).

---

Please implement this and I won't mention that "favourite" is also misspelled...

Answer (score 1):

The question [I asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250830/favourite-button-tooltip-is-incorrect) about this gave me the answer that it is telling you:

> The tooltip is telling you in what situation to click the star ("This is a favorite question").
>
> It is also telling you that this can be undone ("(click again to undo)").

Now, that makes sense - but it is not consistent with other buttons on SE.

The 'accept answer' button says (emphasis mine):

> ***Click to*** accept this answer because it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution (click again to undo) <sub>when unclicked</sub>
>
> ***Click to*** undo acceptance of this answer; you accepted this answer [DATE]  <sub>when clicked</sub>

That's the simplest solution to this (and to make it more *consistent with the site*) is, add 'Click to' to the message and change the message *again* when it has been clicked. ie (in bold and italics is the change, the 'optionally' is optional ;):

> ***Click to make*** <s>T</s>this <s>is</s> a favorite question (click again to undo)  <sub>when unclicked</sub>
>
> ***Click to remove this from your favorites*** (optionally); you added this as a favorite on [DATE] <sub>when clicked;</sub>

It should, as you said, be easy to implement this - because you already know when the state changes - so you can just change the message depending on what class the button has!

---

**Another option** is to follow the voting symbols which simply say:

> This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear <sub>when unclicked</sub>
>
> This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear (click again to undo)<sub>when clicked</sub>

So, just make it:

> ***Make*** <s>T</s>this <s>is</s> a favorite question <sub>when unclicked</sub>
>
> ***Make*** <s>T</s>this <s>is</s> a favorite question (click again to undo) <sub>when unclicked</sub>